# Ajax always refesh page on success

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have built a successful the implementation of Ajax on my Java Web App on a registry of Contacts, but when I registry a new contact on the success of the ajax my page refreshes! I don't want my page to refresh on success, I just want to show a success message. Here is my code:

```
alta: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "altaContacto.con", //servlet
            data: {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                phone: $("#phone").val(),
                company: $("#company").val(),
                subject: $("#subject").val(),
                message: $("#message").val()
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data.estatus === "OK")
                {
                    alert("Tnx for registry.");
                } else
                {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            } //END OF SUCCESS
        });
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing? Many Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling your ajax function?

Comment: What function/event is invoking this ajax call?

Comment: i'm guessing your refresh is when you submit a form? you'll want to capture and kill the event if that is the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call this function you must also stop default propagation of the form. For example:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    alta(); // call the function
    return false;
});
```

That's all

Comment: Thanks! This was my solution! Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you must add in your function 'alta' the event handler i.e,. `alta : funtiton(event)`, and after that you added the event handler, in the end, you need cancel the event without stopping further propagation of the event. Proof this code:

`alta: function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "altaContacto.con", //servlet
            data: {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                phone: $("#phone").val(),
                company: $("#company").val(),
                subject: $("#subject").val(),
                message: $("#message").val()
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data.estatus === "OK")
                {
                    alert("Tnx for registry.");
                } else
                {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            } //END OF SUCCESS
        }); 
    event.preventDefault(); 
}`

I hope help you.  For more information, visit this web: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault